# Can I show friend's (trip companion) hotel reservation at European port of entry?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen-visas, frankfurt

I am traveling to Paris via Frankfurt from the USA. I got my schengen visa from the French embassy. After getting the visa, it turned out that a friend of mine would be visiting Europe at the same time, so we decided to tour together.

He is going to reach Paris earlier in the day, so he has booked a hotel room for both of us. So my earlier hotel reservation which I submitted at visa application will have to be cancelled.

In this case, **will it be okay if I show his hotel reservation to the immigration officer at Frankfurt as proof of accommodation** ?

Or will I need to have a reservation in my name ? I don't want to do that because most refundable reservations need one to cancel at least a day before arrival, so I wont be able to cancel if I keep the reservation alive till I clear immigration on my arrival in Frankfurt.

Advice would be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can show a reservation that differs from that which you provided with your Schengen visa application, but should use some caution in doing so. If your friend's hotel reservation does not include your name, ask that it be added. You may create a problem cancelling what you submitted with your application, and showing one in the name of someone not related to you, and not mentioned in your visa application. If you're entering in Frankfurt, and immediately going on to join your friend in Paris, that evidence of accommodation should be all that you need.